# Switch between two JQuery Datatables

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

I have two JQuery datatables (datatables.net), one with messages and the second one with contacts. I would like to load them without refreshing the page, i.e. if I click link1 I get messages displayed, if I click link2 I get messages table disapear and contacts displayed. I can get it by placing tables in different divs and use .show and .hide on those. But what if I have 20 different tables I need to display with just one at a moment. It would be probably a lot of memory usage at the client side to load all 20 tables and hide those. I'm kind of stuck and overflowed).

I have tried the following:

```
<a href='#' onclick='test_widget();return false;'

<script type="text/javascript">
function test_widget()
{   $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'contacts.php', 
        data:$('#test_widget').serialize(), 
        success:function(data)
        {   $('#test_widget').html(data);   
        }, 
    error:function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {   $("#test_widget").html(errorThrown + ': ' + this.url);  
        },
    dataType:'html'
    });
}
</script>
<div id='test_widget'></div>
```

And then the contacts.php:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped checked-in has-checkbox" id="dtable">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Last Name</th>
   <th>First Name</th>
   <th>Middle Name</th>
   <th>Email</th>
   <th>Phone</th>
   <th> </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
 <tbody>
  <?
$res=mysql_query('SELECT * FROM people ORDER BY lname LIMIT 1000');
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){

  ?>

  <tr class="gradeA">
  <td><?=$row['lname']?> </td>
  <td><?=$row['fname']?> </td>
  <td><?=$row['patronymic']?> </td>
  <td class="center"><?=$row['email']?> </td>
  <td class="center"><?=$row['phones']?> </td>
  <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
</tr>
<? } ?>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

what back-end language are you using for this?
If you need to only show one table at a time, and is concerned about hiding (display:none) several divs, then just send an AJAX request backend and render the appropriate table.

Comment: I'm using PHP. The server side PHP script connects to the mysql database, fetch the data and render the dable. I was trying to POST its output with Ajax, the table shows up but its not an Ajax Table anymore, it is just HTML.

Comment: Sorry, I just did all over again, and it worked! Thank you. The question I'm still running into - can the same be done with a slider or XChart?